# Unzipping a folder( not empty ) to a new named folder

Tags: unzip

I have a folder called `newfast.zip` in my remote server. I required to `unzip` as `xyz` folder. ( say xyz is my new folder name ), I tried like this:

```
[xxxxx@xxxxxautosuggest unzip]$ unzip newfast.zip xyz
Archive:  newfast.zip
caution: filename not matched:  xyz
[mohamear@stic-scm-autosuggest unzip]$ cl
```

But I turn with error. any one help me here please?

**And any one suggest me the good tutorial page to learn all useful command of `putty`**

Comment: how its related to putty? it can be any ssh tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested work around: Create a directory, lets say zipcontent and then unzip the content into that dir: `unzip file.zip -d zipcontent/`

Comment: I am finding a new folder as zipcontent and inside there is another folder called `file` - actually can't we have only the contents o the `file.zip` in to `zipcontent` - if possible suggest me a soluction

Comment: so you mean to say you having only a directory called `file` inside `zipcontent` and nothing else?

Comment: I don't know I am undrestand properlty. It all works fine. I need to unzip the file with the name of what i assign. at preset it do. but it puts as folder inside of other folder. instead if it placed all contents to other folder instead of putting a folder that would be fine. ( just extract the contents to folder)

Comment: workaround is, move the `file` folder outside `zipcontent` folder and delete `zipcontent` folder

Answer (score 0):

Suggested workaround: Unzip the folder to whatever it unzips to and rename it afterwards.

Comment: I tried like that, It reading all ( showing a lit of files ) But after it done there is no new folder found